# Android - ScrollView Scrolling is not working in android 7.0

Tags: android, scrollview, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-version

This activity is having 'Appbar Layout' and 'Toolbar' for the 'Actionbar' functions. When we entering data within 'soft keyboard' scrolling properly in android 4.4 version, but it is not Scrolling properly in android 7.0 version. I did some changes to AndroidManifest.xml also. But haven't good result.

Below is my coding.

**MainActivity.java**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @InjectView(R.id.sign_up_profile_country_auto)
    AutoCompleteTextView countryAutoTextView;

    @InjectView(R.id.profile_scroll_view)
    ScrollView profileScrollView;

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    }


    @OnClick(R.id.sign_up_profile_country_auto)
    public void goScrollUp(){

        profileScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.threeiteam.weightstripz">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.threeiteam.weightstripz.activity.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorBlue"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            style="@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/toolbar_layout_top_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/next_button_layout_width"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_next_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:text="@string/next_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

                </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/profile_scroll_view">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_between_icon_and_text">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/active_profile_head_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/active_radio_group"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_between_icon_and_text"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/profile_male_radio_button"
                        style="@style/radioButtonStyle1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/gender_male"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_between_icon_and_text"/>


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/profile_female_radio_button"
                        style="@style/radioButtonStyle1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/gender_female"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>


                </RadioGroup>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_distance">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/active_profile_birthday"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/linear_bottom_border"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_between_welcome_layout_and_steps_layout"
                    android:id="@+id/profile_birthday_layout">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text=""
                        android:hint="@string/hint_birth_date"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size"
                        android:id="@+id/birthday_text_view"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/small_font_size"
                    android:text="@string/label_calorie_goal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/large_font_size"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/section_distance"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_between_welcome_layout_and_steps_layout"
                    android:text="@string/label_location"
                    android:id="@+id/location_text_view"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/sign_up_profile_country_auto"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font_size"
                        android:hint="@string/hint_country"/>

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by not scrolling 'properly'?

Comment: Please remove android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" from AndroidManifes. it is work for me..

Comment: not scrolling means when I input values for the edit text the softkeyboard is appearing and other content can scroll in android 4.4, but not in android 7.0

Comment: @ Umesh AHIR - it's not the solution for my issue.

Comment: when I'm entering data for the bottom 'AutoCompleteEditText', I can't see what i'm typing due to scrolling issue

Comment: add fillViewPort property to true in ScrollView

Comment: I had the same issue when I displayed error in edittext. I removed focus from the edittext onscroll

Comment: i did it. but not having good result @MinnuKaAnae

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do anything for this.

Please change some code and work it.

remove

```
 @OnClick(R.id.sign_up_profile_country_auto)
public void goScrollUp(){

    profileScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
```

also remove 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden" from AndroidManifes.

when you click on AutoCompleteTextView screen automatically scroll to up..

Comment: I did. but nothing. when I'm entering data for the bottom edit text, I can't see what i'm typing

Comment: i did. but nothing. when I'm entering data for the bottom 'AutoCompleteEditText', I can't see what i'm typing due to scrolling issue

Comment: Please can you show me what @style/AppTheme.NoActionBar is inside

Comment: it must be 
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: yes I already have that style <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: yes i got you issues, you have end two  </LinearLayout> in  android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar please do correct this..

Comment: No I entered that </Linearlayout> mistakenly in the question post.

Comment: OK.. so now only one can help you NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView

Comment: Man use NestedScrollView, I already answered your question. There are some views that can to conflict with ScrollView, so the best solution will be to use NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `nestedScrollView`. There was some times, when my `ScrollView` not scrolled, I used `NestedScrollView` and that worked great.